# Ansible: How to assemble files by removing headers?

Tags: csv, ansible

we have multiple csv files to concatenate based on requirements. Each csv file contains headers and we cannot change them as it is from source. I have so many fragments to combine.

***Example CSV1***

```
hostname,ip,zone
host1,1.3.2.4,EU
host2,1.3.2.5,EU
```

***Example CSV2***

```
hostname,ip,zone
host32,8.3.2.4,US
host22,8.3.2.5,US
```

***Final Ouput required is***

```
hostname,ip,zone
host1,1.3.2.4,EU
host2,1.3.2.5,EU
host32,8.3.2.4,US
host22,8.3.2.5,US
```

I'm trying to do using ***Ansible playbook***

```
- assemble:
    src: /home/mycsvDirectory
    dest: /home/newCSV/mycombined.csv
```

The above assemble works perfectly, but the headers are included everytime. I was looking to do have only one header after all the fragments are combined as per expected output.  How to do this in ansible efficiently? ( I can think of a way to loop through the files and do, but that my be inefficient to do on 100's of files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `assemble` module really isn't the right tool for semantically merging files (that is, merging files in a way that depends on the content of the files).  The easiest solution to your problem would be to stop putting the header in all of the fragment files.

If dropping the header lines isn't an option, the easiest solution with Ansible is probably to write a custom module to handle it (use the `csv` module to parse all the fragments, then use `csv.writer` or similar to generate your output).

There are several hacky workarounds you could use.  For example, you run use a `command:` block to run `sed -i '2,$ {/^hostname/d}'` on the file after assembling it.

Comment: thank you for quick response. Any existing methods in ansible i could use ; like putting an omit filter or something? (Otherwise I like your idea of sed)